# Command switch to toggle Notepads word wrap

Tags: command-line-arguments

I have a costumer showing Notepad with a large set of data that looks totally misaligned if word wrap is on and I want to force it off. Is there a command switch to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is a command switch to do this at all.  If you want to force it off all the time then you may want to edit the registry:

```
Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Notepad
Name: fWrap
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 0
```

You could even create a .reg file and put it in a batch file to run it and reset it every time notepad runs.

Usually though if you have word wrap turned off, when you open it up again, it will still be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

you could just turn it off by going to Format -> Word Wrap.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is any command-line option to do that.

You can however set the default behavior by setting the registry-value HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad\fWrap to 0.

Depending on your exact requirements, you might be able to solve your problem by making a bat-file that modifies the registry before starting Notepad. That would be a rather large hack, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use Wordpad instead of Notepad, it has word wrap off by default.